# Access Denied when viewing S3 Files from AWS S3 Panel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I received the following error when I try to view the file from my S3 Bucket using the AWS S3 Panel. It seems weird because I am able to login as the user then I should be able to view the file.

HEre is my error

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>
Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified
</Message>
<ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue/>
<RequestId>79XXXXXXAD655E52</RequestId>
<HostId>
6JxxxxxxxxxxxolbRqN293/5dLQtNq2DU0oO+gsqYwcxxxxxxxxxxxx4QIWmJwvIK4BA=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: AWS S3 panel means AWS Dashboard correct?

Answer (score 0):

Check your bucket permissions and allow the user to read and view (enable read  and view permissions).